# Determinant n exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Prove that $\det A^n=(\det A)^n$.

Proof by induction.

Suppose $n=1.$

$\det A^n= (\det A)^n$

$\det A^1=(\det A)^1$

$\det A= \det A$

Now assume $n=k$ is true. Suppose $n=k+1$

$\det A^{k+1}= (\det A)^{k+1}$

$\det(A^k A)= (\det A)^{k+1}$

$(\det A^k)  (\det A)= (\det A)^{k+1}$

$(\det A^k) (\det A)= (\det A)^{k+1}$

To see the exercise clearly [enter here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mjRDSaDXm2Sl-ubh0Esy0G1tCIAUhvb5c4MQqibnAXs/edit?usp=sharing).

It this prove complete and correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write $something = something\ else$ before you've shown or assumed it to be true. Your thoughts are OK, but you need to write it a bit more clearly. Start with what you know and build towards what you want:

$$\det A^{k+1} = \det(A^k A) = (\det A^k) (\det A) = | \text{by ind. hyp.} | = (\det A)^k (\det A) = (\det A)^{k+1}.$$

The same goes for the case $n = 1$:

$$\det A^{n} = \det A^1 = \det A = (\det A)^1 = (\det A)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

In you last step you must replace $(detA^k)$ in  $(detA^k) (detA)= (detA)^{k+1}$ by $(detA)^k$(by induction hypothesis) and thus you will get  $(detA)^k (detA)= (detA)^{k+1}$, and hence proved by induction.